# Unable to use Cassandra from Presto

Tags: hadoop, cassandra-2.0, hadoop2, presto

I have setup presto 0.76, Cassandra 2.1.2 and created a `mykeyspace` and a table to it. I started both the Cassandra daemons and Presto daemons. When I try to query Cassandra using presto CLI it returns

`presto:mykeyspace> select * from userinfo;
Query 20141216_181006_00021_me4u4 failed: replicate_on_write is not a column defined in this metadata`

So is there any way to get over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latest version 0.88 with fixes for cassandra, http://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.88.html

Comment: Hey thanks, But is there any way to workout the above versions compatibility issue.?